# android:gravity option is not getting with Imageview

Tags: android

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".35" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/txt_loginpage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".65" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/edtCardnum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/request" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I cannot get the `android:gravity` option with the `Imageview`, but I can get it with `Textview`.

Is there any thing wrong in my code.

If I change this to `Textview` then `android:gravity` option is working,but not with `Imageview` .

```
 <ImageView 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
         android:id="@+id/txt_loginpage"
         android:background="@drawable/yellow"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

android:gravity option is used to set the content of the holder view to set at particular position inside holder view.It works same like alignment attribute of a word document page.when you use imageview there is no content inside it,it just have bitmap and to set different position of that bitmap at particular position you can use scaletype option.Otherwise you have to use the gravity option to the parent of the imageview.

put gravity on parent linearlayout if you want the same effect.